# DRY the throwing of ArgumentNullException("ParameterName")?

Tags: c#

I am using this code in a lot of places:

```
if (ParameterName == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("ParameterName");
}
```

But I think this is not DRY. The only difference here is `ParameterName`. Is it ok to use these lines everywhere, or is there a way to make it DRY?

Comment: This is where you wish you had C macros

Comment: @Demetri no, it really isn't! Even if you did, there's nothing to stop you using the C preprocessor on C# files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks pretty DRY to me. :) You can use expressions to somewhat reduce the amount of code you need to write:

```
    public static void ThrowIfNull(Expression<Func<object>> expression)
    {
        var res = expression.Compile();
        if (res.Invoke() == null)
        {
            var lambda = (LambdaExpression) expression;
            var member = (MemberExpression) lambda.Body;
            throw new ArgumentNullException(member.Member.Name);
        }
    }

    public void SomeMethod(object someParameter)
    {
        ThrowIfNull(() => someParameter);
    }
```

but frankly i'd go with Re-sharper templates (or VS code snippets) instead.

**Edit:** A quick test on my machine shows, that on average it takes about 0.22 milliseconds per call to execute `ThrowIfNull` 1000000 times with different (not null) arguments. With first call being ~20 times slower (perhaps repeated compilation is optimized and/or cached in some way, tho i am not competent enough on that subject to make any claims). Is it slower then one equality check? Well, obviously. But it is still unlikely to become any kind of a bottleneck in real life scenario, unless overused. As i said, however, i would not use it. The original code looks clear and short enough to me, even shorter, when templated. So i always go with simple explicit `null` check.

Comment: You mean the condition checking is DRY itself. Yes, I have found these lines a lot in ASP.NET MVC 5 source which led me to think this is not bed.

Comment: Won't that be quite slow, compiling an expression each time? A null check should be cheap so you can do lots of them - compiling code for each one seems like it might slow things down a lot.

Comment: Why are you using an expression for this? Seems a little overkill to me, unless of course I'm missing something blindingly obvious.

Comment: @MrKWatkins, slow compared to what? To the original solution? Yes, of course. See my edit.

Comment: @Joe, to get a parameter name without manually typing a string :)

Comment: It strikes me as quite a bit awkward to depend on the structure of the body of the lambda, and only in the null-case. I think I'd rather just supply the parameter name and thus abstract just the null-comparison of the original code.

Comment: @plc, you can do that, Joe's answer provides a nice implementation of this approach. I'm simply providing an alternative solution. Being said, i am not convinced by your reasoning. Such "dependencies" are not uncommon. Actually you can find them all over the .Net. Take `String.Format` for example. Does the fact that you have to pass the correct number of arguments strickes you the same way? Is it good enough reason not to use it?

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak It's not the slowness for a single call I'm worried about as it may well be cached. But you'll have calls like this all over the app you'll be compiling extra code to memory all over the place. Seems overkill to me when you could just type in the parameter name. And if you use ReSharper you could even add an [InvokerParameterName] annotation to help ensure the correct name is being passed.

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak If you did want to tie the name in with an expression then I'd probably pass the value *and* the expression. Check the value for null (which wouldn't involve compilation) and only then parse the expression to get the parameter name.

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak Ugh, obviously! Sorry for a dumb comment.

Answer (score 13):

Google Guava's [`Precondition`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull%28T,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) class contains good patterns for this problem. For example, the `checkNotNull` method is the following:

```
T checkNotNull(T reference, String errorMessageTemplate, Object... errorMessageArgs)
```

Usage:

```
checkNotNull(parameter, "parameter cannot be null");
```

Note its return value. If the value is not `null` it returns the `referencce`, so you can use it in the following way:

```
public MyClass(MyObject dependency) {
    this.dependency = checkNotNull(dependency, "dependency cannot be null");
}
```

It also supports error message templates with `%s`.

Although it's a Java library, you can implement the same methods in C# too, they are really simple.

See also: [Preconditions Explained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained)

Comment: +1 for mentioning preconditions. This seems like a good time to introduce code contracts (and the DbC principle in general).

Comment: I am using C#..

Comment: @user960567: "Although it's a Java library, you can implement the same methods in C# too, they are really simple."

Comment: As of Java 7, you could use the built-in `Objects.requireNotNull` method. But then again... this is a C# question :)

Answer (score 10):

If you just want a short syntax, you could use Code Contracts.

Either

```
Contract.Requires( x != null );
```

or

```
Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>( x != null, "x" )
```

depending on whether the exact exception type is important to you. There is also some configuration to be done, depending on if you want these checks only for debug, or also for release.

I should point out, however, that Code Contracts are really about much more than simple argument checks, and it has its own pros and cons. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Note that `Contract.Requires(` does *not* necessarily throw any exception.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 8):

I would go for a generic extension method for this:

```
public static void ThrowIfNull<T>(this T parameter, string name) where T : class
{
    if (data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
}
```

This way, you can call

```
Parameter.ThrowIfNull("Name");
```

If you're calling this on a property, you could use [CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), this won't work from a method though.

Comment: If you have access to the new C# 6.0 features, you can could use the new nameof(...) operator

`if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));`

The compiler will catch any parameter name mismatchs which may occur if you rename a parameter.

Comment: @JoeKing would `nameof(data)` just come back with `"data"`? I don't think it will cascade down. I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, it really only helps in the case where you rename a parameter. On a side note, the `nameof()` operator can also come in very handy when implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, as property renaming has to be one of the main sources of data binding bugs.

Answer (score 5):

You could try to extract it to a method, but you'd still have to call it for every parameter and you will lose the information, what the parameter's name is....

```
CheckNull(object ParameterName){
   if(parameterName == null){
      throw new ArgumentNullException("some param was null, no clue which...");
   }
}
```